# Define relationships in database for CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Im trying out a sample project in CakePHP. It is taken from the cakePHP documentation. It has a total of 4 tables and two of the are listed here.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    group_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);
```

As you can see the id from the users table is added to the posts table as a foreign key in the form of `user_id`. But in the sample there are no relationships defined. I mean normally we would explicitly define `user_id` as a foreign key by adding the constraints (in my case using the Relation View of phpMyAdmin). But it is not done here or we are not instructed to do so. When using `Cake Bake console` to bake our `Models` do we need this foreign key constraints in place or does cakephp figure them out automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Convention over configuration**

Cakephp figures them out automatically for you but you have to follow the [naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)